# Broken Display - Black Screen

Tags: display

I was changing some settings in CompizConfig and things were starting to look bad and kind of glitchy, so I clicked Reset to Defaults in CompizConfig and suddenly, everything disappeared except my background.
I had no windows and no launcher, so naturally I rebooted because I couldn't do anything and now, since I dual boot, I select Ubuntu and it flashes the Ubuntu screen with the dots like normal and then the screen is just black. Even fail safe graphics mode gives me a black screen.

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: guess you have messed up with your graphics! Do you use any graphics drivers like bumblebee? I suggest you to reinstall my ubuntu again (If you haven't got any important files)

Comment: what is your graphics card and can you connect to internet in Ctrl+Alt+F2 mode?

Comment: I don't use any graphics drivers, besides whatever was installed by default. My graphics card is an Intel HD Graphics 4000 according to my Windows side. What is Ctrl+Alt+F2 mode?

Comment: Press Ctrl+ Alt+ F2 and if you can connect to internet without screen, then run the command `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel`

Comment: I ended up using Puppy Linux to recover all my files and then reinstalling the operating system. Thanks though! I'll keep it in mind for the (hopefully unrealized) similar future situation.